# Firefox WebExtensions eating all memory

Tags: linux, firefox, memory

Happens both with 68.9 and 75 I've used a little bit.

The top of top is like this.

```
Tasks: 192 total,   2 running, 190 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 13.5 us,  4.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 80.3 id,  1.8 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.5 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7915.4 total,     62.1 free,   7711.0 used,    142.4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   8192.0 total,    929.9 free,   7262.1 used.     33.9 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                  
 6958 pooh      20   0   12.7g   5.1g    680 R  96.0  66.0 135:00.81 WebExtensions                                                                                                                                                            
  898 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  16.6   0.0   5:06.82 kswapd0                                                                                                                                                                  
 6852 pooh      20   0 4199116 923216  19992 S  10.6  11.4 237:11.23 firefox
```

It has eaten all the memory and was licking away the crumbs left of the swap at the time. Needless to say it was totally unusable.

Is there an easy way to see which webextension (if any) is responsible for that? about:memory didn't give much clue.

Comment: The only way to know is to disable all your extensions, and then to enable them back, one by one. As soon as you observe a surge in RAM usage, you'll know which one is eating your RAM.

Comment: Well, was doing it as well, now it has boiled down to about 3 extensions, but the situation doesn't happen right away, but with time. So was thinking maybe there's some firefox's innate introspection available to facilitate it.

Comment: Not really. Firefox manages its own RAM and CPU usage, and watches over WebExts so that they don't do anything stupid, but that's about it. You can try to restart Firefox in Safe Mode. This will clear the extension cache, as well as disable them all. You restart it again in regular mode and see if your problem's still there. You can also uninstall all your extensions and clean install them again. Remember that some add-ons, like Grease/ViolentMonkey, or Decentraleyes, run third-party scripts and call resources you won't have much control over.

Comment: In Firefox, open your menu from the 3bars at the top right, click __More__ there you should see __Task Manager__. This is not Windows Task Manager. This should allow you to see which extension(s) are chewing up your memory. Hope this helps. Oops I thought you were using Windows, still, it is the same in Linux.